# How to draw route between multiple points in Google Maps?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-directions-api, google-polyline

I have implemented google maps in my app and there are several points i need to mark on the map. I was able to mark them with markers but the problem i am facing is trying to draw the path between all those points.

I tried using polyline but it just draws a straight line between point A and point B.
I also tried google maps directionsAPI and it shows all the possible routes between A and B.

My question is how do i draw proper route between point A -> point B -> point C -> point D. I want the route to start at point A then go through B and C and end at point C. ( I do not want to see alternate routes)

Can anybody shed some light on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass one or more (list of) | (pipe) separated lat longs (lat,longs) as waypoints to google's direction API. The overview polyline returned in response will contain a path from source to destination via all the way points you specified in your request.

copying from Google's doc

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?
origin=sydney,au&destination=perth,au
&waypoints=via:-37.81223%2C144.96254%7Cvia:-34.92788%2C138.60008
&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Read: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/overview

Scroll to waypoints section, its pretty straight forward :)

**Suggestion:** If you are passing a list of | (pipe) separated lat longs ensure to properly encode comma (,) to %2C between lat and long values and ensure not to leave any space between them. Properly encode | as well.

Comment: %2C between lat n long and %7C between 2 different locations , right?

Comment: @zyfe3r: Please consider accepting the answer if it helped

Comment: @Zyfe3r Correct

Answer (score 2):

Here's simple and clean requet you can use

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=28.430348957506485,76.98648305807664&destination=28.599890024415032,77.39881368551802&waypoints=28.532347609852128,77.19007345114302|28.58602324471669,77.33358236227583&key=Your_API_KEY](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=28.430348957506485,76.98648305807664&destination=28.599890024415032,77.39881368551802&waypoints=28.532347609852128,77.19007345114302%7C28.58602324471669,77.33358236227583&key=Your_API_KEY)